# hover img in fbml

Tags: html, css, facebook, fbml, image

I'm trying to work out how to do a hover img in an fbml on a 'like to reveal content page.

If that doesn't make sense, here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
http://www.facebook.com/sonyericsson?v=app_6009294086

If you hover over the video and phone while you're not a fan it prompts you to like the page to view the content.

THANKS GUYS

Comment: Wouldn't that be done in the build process of the landing page (ie. in the CSS for the hover state of the image/element)?

Comment: yeah thats what i am after, the css i am using isnt working

Answer (score 1):

Just worked it out,

you need an a href about the hover img to make it work, if anyone wants further info just let me know